# nginx with php and rewrite rule

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I'd like to set my nginx server with php, and a simple rewrite rule. I tried to make a rewrite rule, that any urls which points to non existing file or directory, rewrites to /index.php?q=. I created this nginx.conf:

```
events {
}

http {
  include fastcgi.conf;
  server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     www.example.com;
    index           index.php;
    root            /var/www/html/www.example.com;
    location / {
      index     index.php;
      if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
      }
      if (!-d $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?r=$1 last;
      }
    }
    location ~ \.php {
      try_files $uri =404;
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9999;
    }
  }
}
```

This works, but not in every case. It perfectly rewrites utls like tihs:

http://www.example.com/111/222/333

But two case not works as i want:

http://www.example.com/111/222/333.php

drops 404 error.

And www.example.com/forum/index.php exists, so the www.example.com/forum/index.php executes index.php in forum directory, this is fine. But www.example.com/forum url rewrites to /index.php, not execute index.php in forum directory as i want.

How can i solve this two problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is absolutely wrong, replace location / content with a single line:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to format you redirect to be something like this if you want to redirect to an index file within a specific directory

```
rewrite ^/((.*/)*)(.*)$ /$1index.php?q=$3
```